# How to set default value for a column on CreateTables()?

Tags: go, gorp

I am using [gorp](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp), and I want to create a table with `DbMap#CreateTables()` by setting a default value for a column.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation of this feature is currently being reviewed by the project's collaborators.
See the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp/pull/209).